# Jackson XML: Serializing Repeats

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-dataformat-xml

I have a class

```
public class Catalog {
    public final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
}
```

How should I configure **com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper** to produce such xml (do not want annotations on the POJO but prefer the repeat tag name to be generated from the repeat type, e.g. Item )?

```
<catalog>
  <items>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </items>
</catalog>
```

Comment: you can't achieve it without annoations or custom serializers / deserializers

Comment: can you please point me to some examples with custom ser/deser?

Comment: You can have a look at https://spin.atomicobject.com/2016/07/01/custom-serializer-jackson/, it is for json , but you can customize it as per your impl. But I think `@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(localName = "items")
 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "item")
    public final List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();` will be easier for you, just two annotation

Comment: Thanks, @Hermant, I will check it. I know about annotations but they are not in scope.